# How to modify color and size for Coil image placeholder in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-image, android-icons, coil

I'm using Coil `1.3.2` in Jetpack Compose and I have an `Image` like this

```kotlin
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        data = imageUrl,
        onExecute = { _, _ -> true },
        builder = {
            placeholder(R.drawable.icon)
        }
    ),
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .aspectRatio(1f)
)
```

How can I set a custom color and size for my placeholder icon ?
I didn't find any examples on the [documentation](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `painter.state` to see if the image is still loading, and use `Box` to display the desired placeholder. Note that the `Image` to be loaded must be in the view hierarchy, just defining `rememberImagePainter` won't start loading.

You can use either `Image` or `Icon` for the placeholder: if you need to change tint color, the second option seems cleaner:

```
Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
    val painter = rememberImagePainter(data = imageUrl)
    Image(
        painter = painter,
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(1f)
    )
    if (painter.state !is ImagePainter.State.Success) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon),
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Color.Blue,
            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

I'm using `contentAlignment = Alignment.Center` to center static size placeholder inside the `Box`, also you can add `Modifier.matchParentSize()` to the placeholder so it'll be the same size as the image, use `fillMaxSize(part)` to take `part` of parent space, etc.

Also you can use [AnimatedVisibility](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatedvisibility) instead of `if` to add an animation.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot do that using the resource directly, but you could use different `placeholder` overload taking the `Drawable` object. You could try and do what you need directly in that object

Answer (score 0):

I find it much easier to use the `Box {...}` component and add the Image/Placeholder composable underneath the AsyncImage.

Like this:

```
Box {
    PlaceholderComposable()
    AsyncImage(
        model = url,
        contentDescription = null,
        ...
    )
}
```

But of course - both the image and the composable should have their modifiers set up correctly - so that they cover each other.

I am using Coil 2.4.0.